# Wifi symbol vanishes after using wifite

Tags: wireless, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I use Gnome DE and after I use wifite, the wifi symbol just vanishes and you can't connect to the wifi using GUI. I tried it on many desktop environments and most of them have this problem (except deepin)

I would like to know if there is any solution for this or how can I bring up the icon?

Comment: and idk if it's gnome's problem or wifite's problem coz it works fine in kali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use wifite it disables network manager and puts your wifi device down.

Try running `sudo service network-manager restart`

And -depending on the name of your wireless card- run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

Now you have to run `sudo lshw -C network` in order to see what your wifi card's name is. It will look like

```
*-network               
description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 24:ec:99:21:c9:29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=3.8.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.74 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3000000-c3003fff
```

What you want to look at is `logical name` and when you run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` replace `wlan0` with whatever the logical name of your wireless card is

Answer (score 0):

This puts your wifi card out of monitor mode:

```
sudo airmon-ng stop wlp3s0mon
```

It was suggested from wifite after a if finished all the attacks and it works at least on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following command

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && airmon-ng stop wlan0

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ran `wifite` or `airmon` and you want to use a Wi-Fi connection, run these commands after closing the tools (the first disables monitor mode and the second restarts the network manager):

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0
```

and:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).